# Error on building the Titanium Mobile SDK from source

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, scons, titanium-modules

I downloaded the source code of titanium mobile sdk from github. I installed python ,scons ,jdk and android sdk in windows 7. I set path for java,android sdk,etc in environment variable.
but on compiling with scons , following error is rised.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Shihab>cd  C:\Project\titanium_mobile

C:\Project\titanium_mobile>scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Building MobileSDK version 3.1.0, githash 2d79a72
KeyError: 14:
  File "C:\Project\titanium_mobile\SConstruct", line 115:
    sdk = AndroidSDK(ARGUMENTS.get("android_sdk", None), 14)
  File "C:\Project\titanium_mobile\support\android\androidsdk.py", line 49:
    self.set_api_level(api_level)
  File "C:\Project\titanium_mobile\support\android\androidsdk.py", line 53:
    self.find_platform_dir()
  File "C:\Project\titanium_mobile\support\android\androidsdk.py", line 127:
    old_style_dir = os.path.join(self.android_sdk, 'platforms', android_api_leve
ls[api_level])

C:\Project\titanium_mobile>
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This forum post](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/140526/solution-application-installer-abnormal-process-termination) says that **KeyError: NN** means that Android API version NN was not found. Do you have that particular version? (API 14 == Android 4.0)

Comment: yes.. i updated the android sdk using sdk manager  and it works like a charm...........

Comment: I had the same error but the mentioned solution didn't work for me because I already had this SDK Version installed. It turned out that I've set my $ANDROID_SDK Path wrong. It was set to ~/Development/android/sdk. Changing it to /Users/manu/Development/android/sdk solved this problem.

Comment: This solved it for me! Good to finally get it to build.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just download Titanium Studio? from the appcelerator page, you can try to create a project there and see if your doing all the configurations correctly

Comment: no. my intention is to familiarize titanium open source project and to get involved in the project.